# Disable Paste in Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, parcel, visual-studio-monaco

I was trying to implement the Monaco editor on a web project using parcel as a bundler, but find it quite difficult to prevent a paste action (I do not want the users to paste codes in the editor).

This was how I initialised the editor

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.main.js';

// set monaco web workers url
window.MonacoEnvironment = {
  getWorkerUrl: (moduleId, label)=> {
        if (label === 'json') {
            return '../language/json/json.worker.js';
        }
        if (label === 'css') {
            return '../language/css/css.worker.js';
        }
        if (label === 'html') {
            return '../language/html/html.worker.js';
        }
        if (label === 'typescript' || label === 'javascript') {
            return '../language/typescript/ts.worker.js';
        }
        return '../editor/editor.worker.js';
  }
};


export const monacoCreate = (MonacoConfig = {}, doc) => monaco.editor.create(doc, {
  value: [
    'function x() {',
    '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
    '}'
  ].join('\n'),
  language: "javascript",
  theme: "white",
  mouseWheelZoom: true,
  readOnly: false,
  showUnused: true,
  wordWrap: "on",
  selectionClipboard: false,
  ...MonacoConfig
});
```

This was how I created an instance of the editor in a `div` with id `code`

```js
const select = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const editor = monacoCreate({ language: language.html }, select('#code'));
```

The challenge now is on reading the `Monaco docs`, I can't find an inbuilt method to prevent a paste event in the editor, neither have I found a walk around it. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround this.

Monaco has an inbuilt `onKeyDown()` method that returns an event(Details about the keys pressed and keys not pressed).
All I did was to get the `keyCode` of the key pressed and also check if the `CTRL` or `CMD` key has been pressed
Hence, on pasting an item to the Monaco editor, I prevent the default action when `CtrlOrCmd+v` and `CtrlOrCmd+c` keys are pressed.

below shows how I implemented the fix

```js
 editor.onKeyDown((event)=>{
    const {keyCode, ctrlKey, metaKey} = event;
    if((keyCode === 33 || keyCode ===52) && (metaKey || ctrlKey)){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't the user still be able to right click and select paste from the context menu?

Comment: @luekbaja, this approach targets key combinations. However, you can also disable paste/copy from the context menu through your `css` or `js` files

Comment: how to prevent user to right click on the editor and then paste the code? with the given solution it restrict ctrl+C and ctrl+V but not the right click.